# How do I separate comma separated coordinates for plotting in MapView on iOS?

Tags: ios, coordinates

How would I take a comma separated value NSString *location = "15.009483, -87.485195" and separate them into coordinate values to plot?

I need to put them into CoreData database which has separate fields for each coordinate.

Answer (score 2):

You can use NSArray's `componentsSeparatedByString:` to break the string up into an array. From there you can pull the objects right back out as separate strings.

```
NSString *location = @"15.009483, -87.485195";
NSArray *array = [location componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSString *lat = array[0];
NSString *lon = array[1];
```

Comment: ok yeah, in all honesty I have seen that approach.  i was just wondering if there was a cleaner option, perhaps relating directly to CLLocation or MapKit which took a string and automatically converted it into lat and long pair.  But thanks!

Comment: @marciokoko I'm not aware of any other options using the location frameworks, but I'm not all that familiar with them. If it turns out there isn't there is nothing wrong with this approach from a technical stand point.